# How to access getFragmentManager() method inside a Service?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Service` which be used to add views to the `WindowManager`. The idea is to have something like Facebook chat heads. So even if my application is not running in the foreground, the view will be always present.

The `view` which I need to add to the `WindowManager` should have three tabs. I am using `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` for this purpose

The xml file of the view

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
              android:layout_margin="20dp"
              android:background="#ff0000"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/debugger_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/debugger_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my service, I am inflating the xml file as below in the `onStartCommand()` method.

```
@Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flag, int startId) {

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 200,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    debuggerView = (LinearLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.debugger_main, null);

    debuggerViewPager = (ViewPager) debuggerView.findViewById(R.id.debugger_pager);


    //Facing problem at this line. How to access getFragmentManager() function here ?
    DebuggerPagerAdapter adapter = new DebuggerPagerAdapter();
    debuggerViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    debuggerViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(
        debuggerTabLayout));

    windowManager.addView(debuggerView, params);
}
```

Now in the below line of code, the `DebuggerPagerAdapter` accepts `FragmentManager` as its argument to the constructor. If the below line was written inside an activity, then I could have simply called off `new DebuggerPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager())`, but not sure how to do this inside a Service ?

```
DebuggerPagerAdapter adapter = new DebuggerPagerAdapter();
```

The code for DebuggerPagerAdapter

```
    public class DebuggerPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter  {

  public DebuggerPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
      case 0:
        return MemoryFragment.getInstance();
      case 1:
        return NetworkFragment.getInstance();
      case 2:
        return CpuFragment.getInstance();
    }
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }
}
```

TIA.

Comment: If your app isn't running in the foreground, there's no guarantee that there will even be an `Activity` for the views to exist in.

Comment: I am adding the view to the WindowManager, don't need an activity for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fragments only exist in activities, not elsewhere. You will need to create your own `PagerAdapter` implementation that does not use fragments.

Comment: I have my own implementation of PagerAdapter, updated the code above.

Comment: @thedarkpassenger: Let's try boldface: you will need to create your own `PagerAdapter` implementation **that does not use fragments**.

Comment: got it.. Instead of extending FragmentPagerAdapter I used PagerAdapter. thanks..:)